# Ibus-typing-booster is not working in brave

Tags: brave

I'm using ubuntu 22.04.

ibus-typing-booster is working in firefox,libere writer but not in brave which installed through nix.

Please answer soultion.

Comment: Try installing through their official repositories instead of nix https://brave.com/linux/#debian-ubuntu-mint

Comment: @archisman-panigrahi thanks.. now works